# Convertir numero en fecha y hora javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente numero "43638.65650864583" (obtenido de un timestamp de google sheet) y quiero convertirlo en formato con un javascript "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"

Probe:

```
var date = new Date(43638.65650864583);
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
```

Pero no me trae la fecha correcta.

Comment: ¿Qué representa ese número? Si es un número, lo que estás diciendo es que te de la hora equivalente a 43638... milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 a las 0:00. Es decir, te dará 1 de enero de 1970 a las 1 hora y 43 segundos.

Comment: Ese numero es "22/6/2019 15:45:22" es una marca temporal generada por un formulario. necesito enviarla en un array con otras string. la transforme en numero para que esa fecha no me genere error en el array. y ahora quiero transformarla de nuevo a fecha para pasarla a un id.

Comment: ¿Y sabes el formulario en qué formato te está pasando esa fecha?

Comment: Nop, simplemente me muestra la fecha esa. "22/6/2019 15:45:22"

Comment: Ese número es una fecha unix, una fecha juliana u otra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En JavaScript las fechas se construyen usando milisegundos que han transcurrido desde el 1 de enero de 1970 (lo que se conoce como [Tiempo Unix](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiempo_Unix), o Unix Epoch).

El formulario, parece que te está dando el valor en número de días que han pasado desde el 1 de enero de 1900. Esto es común en las hojas de cálculo (Google Sheets y Microsoft Excel por ejemplo). Lo que necesitas hacer es:

1. Restar el número de días entre el 1 de enero de 1900 y 1 de enero de 1970 (en Microsoft Excel además tendrás que añadir 1 por un bug que cuenta 1900 como año bisiesto cuando no es así).
2. Convertir a milisegundos.

La fórmula del primer paso es esta: `(numeroDeDias - (25567)) * 86400 * 1000)` para Google Sheets. Y `(numeroDeDias - (25567 + 1)) * 86400 * 1000)` para Microsoft Excel.

Prueba con este código:

```js
function numeroAFecha(numeroDeDias, esExcel = false) {
  var diasDesde1900 = esExcel ? 25567 + 1 : 25567;

  // 86400 es el número de segundos en un día, luego multiplicamos por 1000 para obtener milisegundos.
  return new Date((numeroDeDias - diasDesde1900) * 86400 * 1000);
}

var fecha = numeroAFecha(43638.65650864583, true);
console.log(fecha);
```

Ten en cuenta que el resultado dependerá de la hora local del ordenador que ejecute el código.

Comment: Genial me funciono, solo que tuve que poner "25567 + 2" ya que me mostraba junio 23 y no 22 que es la correcta. lo unico que nose porque me muestra 12:45:22, siendo que el GMT-3 esta bien. incluso cuando ejecutas el script aca en oveflow te muestra la hora correcta. 15:45:22. gracias!

Comment: como puedo obtener el resultado inverso? es decir de FechaAnumero?

Comment: @MTDesigner el objeto `Date` tiene un método `getTime()` que te devuelve un número: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date/getTime

Comment: si, pero a ese metodo deberia restarle el numero de diasDesde1900? porque no obtengo el mismo numero que coloca en la hoja de calculo (luego de aplicar el formato "general" a una fecha)

Comment: No, tendrías que pasarlo a la misma unidad (nº de días) y luego sumarle esos días. El número que te devuelve javascript es el número de milisegundos desde el 1 de enero de 1970 (como ya dije en la respuesta). Tienes que dividir ese número por 1000 para pasarlo a segundos, dividirlo por 86400 para pasarlo a días, y sumarle la fecha del 1 de enero de 1970. En una celda de Google Sheets sería: `=tuNumero / 1000 / 86400 + DATE(1970, 1, 1)`

Comment: let fechaSheet = new Date().getTime() / 1000 / 86400 + 25569; asi quedo, muchas gracias!! yo lo habia solamente restado y no me daba el mismo numero